# How to include mp3 file in buildozer.spec python kivy

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        fl = FloatLayout()
        try:
            sound = SoundLoader.load('magic.mp3')
            if sound:
                print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
                print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
                fl.add_widget(Label(text=str("Sound found at %s" % sound.source), pos=(0, 0), font_size=(40)))
                sound.play()
        except Exception as error:
            fl.add_widget(Label(text=str(error), pos=(0, 0), font_size=(40)))
        return fl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

I this code I use magic.mp3 and I want to be able to use it in `.apk` file, but there isn't it. I thought I should add `.mp3` files in `buildozer.spec`:

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mp3
```

And I also added:

```
# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,magic/*.mp3
```

But I cann't play this file, and I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'source'
```

How to fix it? I hope you help me

Comment: Is `magic.mp3` in a folder named `magic`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson no, `magic.mp3` in folder with file `main.py`

Comment: The line `source.include_patterns = assets/*,magic/*.mp3` is including `mp3` files from a `magic` folder.  Try changing it to: source.include_patterns = assets/*,magic.mp3`

Comment: @JohnAnderson I get the same error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'source'`

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Try running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` (with your android device attached) and examine the logcat output. If you see `Audio: Unable to find a loader for  <magic.mp3>` in the output, then you might need to add `ffpyplayer` to your `requirements` in the `spec` file.

Comment: @JohnAnderson When I ran I got: `# Application pushed.# Application started.# Run 'dpkg version'# Cwd None Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 amd64).This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.# Search for Git (git)#  -> found at /usr/bin/git# Search for Cython (cython)# ->found at/usr/local/bin/cython# Search for Java compiler (javac)# ->found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac# Search for Java keytool(keytool)#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool`

Comment: @JohnAnderson I found out, that my error occurs, when SoundLoader can't find file

Comment: You can check what is in your `apk` file. Run `unzip app.apk` (where `app.apk` is your `apk` file). This should unzip the files and folders that are in your `apk` file (you might want to do this in a separate folder). One of the unzipped folders should be `assets`. Inside the `assets` folder, you should see  `private.mp3` file. it is actually a tar archive. You can see what is in that file by doing a `tar tvf private.mp3`. There should be lots of stuff in that file, and that is where your `magic.mp3` file should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a belated answer, FWIW.  I think your problem is not that your mp3 isn't found, but that your file is in mp3.  The SDL2 library in python-for-android doesn't support mp3 at the moment (see https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5412 ).

You should be able to work around this by converting your mp3 file to wav or ogg.

Comment: I understood this for a long time and solved the problem, but since your answer is correct, I will accept it